# What happens in Python when creating a variable of a linked-list node

Tags: python

[This LeetCode solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/insertion-sort-list/solutions/1176552/python3-188ms-solution-explanation-with-visualization/) gives a solution like this:

```
class Solution:
    def insertionSortList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head

        dummy_head = ListNode(val=-5000, next=head)
        last_sorted = head
        curr = head.next

        while curr:
            if curr.val > last_sorted.val:
                last_sorted = last_sorted.next
            else:
                prev = dummy_head
                while prev.next.val < curr.val:
                    prev = prev.next

                last_sorted.next = curr.next
                curr.next = prev.next
                prev.next = curr

            curr = last_sorted.next

        return dummy_head.next
```

I wonder on l14, what's the difference between `curr = head.next` and `curr = last_sorted.next`. Aren't head and last_sorted referencing the same object?

This is what I have experimented in a Python console:

```
python3 -i
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class ListNode:
...     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
...         self.val = val
...         self.next = next
...
>>> head = ListNode(val=0, next=None)
>>> last_sorted = head
>>> tmp = ListNode(val=1, next=None)
>>> head.next = tmp
>>> last_sorted.next
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x10043cca0>
>>> last_sorted.next.val
1
>>> head
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x10043c820>
>>> last_sorted
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x10043c820>
>>> head.next
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x10043cca0>
>>>
```

Comment: *"Aren't head and last_sorted referencing the same object?"* — Before the loop they are, during the loop that might change here: `last_sorted = last_sorted.next`

Comment: I still don't get how the reference of `curr` changes as the reference of `last_sorted` changes. Shouldn't `curr` point to that `0x10043cca0` at all times until you explicitly point `curr` to somewhere else?